# Is it posible to change Android's call ring in an app? If yes, how to achieve it?

Tags: android

I want to make an app that can set up several songs and play them randomly or repeatly when I got a call. Like I sat up song A and song B. When I got a call, the phone rang song A. Then I got another call, the phone rang song B. Is it posible? How to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the sound from an app directly as a global ringtone. But you can let the user select the ringtone from it's storage on his device. The code shows you how does it work in practice.

Let's start with your `MainActivity.java` that execute the `RingtoneManager` get pressed by a `Button`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button btn;
   TextView txtView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      btn = findViewById(R.id.btnSelRingtone);
      txtView = findViewById(R.id.tvRingtone);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            //Intent to select Ringtone.
            final Uri currentTone=
               RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this,
               RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currentTone);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 999);
         }
      });
   }
   @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if(requestCode == 999 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
         txtView.setText("From :" + uri.getPath());
      }
   }
}
```

Add the following code to `activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelRingtone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Select Ringtone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRingtone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnSelRingtone"
        android:text="Ringtone Path" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't forget to add `<user-permission/>` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

**RESULT:**

[image: Select ringtone]

**PS:** I think that's a point where you can start with. Now you know all technologies to continue with your project. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I get it. This permission allows the app to change the user's settings and I can create a service to change the ringtone in settings. If you don't mind I want to ask a final question: how can an app notice there is a call coming in? Thank you again!